# SQLAlchemy compiled statement without percent signs conditionally escaped

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a way to obtain the compiled SQLAlchemy statement without having the percentage signs [conditionally escaped](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_12.html#percent-signs-in-literal-column-now-conditionally-escaped)?

The following MySQL example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import select  


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)


statement = select([User.name]).where(User.name.like('bob%')).limit(10)
query = str(statement.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
print(query)
```

generates a compiled statement with the percent sign escaped:

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.name LIKE 'bob%%' 
  LIMIT 10
```

rather than:

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.name LIKE 'bob%' 
  LIMIT 10
```

I gather this is to ensure that the string can correctly be formatted using the MySQL [pyformat](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L238) parameter style. Is the correct logic for obtaining the later statement simply:

```
print(query % {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just the [.startswith() ColumOperator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.startswith) to create your like by doing

```
statement = select([User.name]).where(User.name.startswith('bob')).limit(10)
```

Comment: Sorry this is just a dummy example. The statement may include freeform SQL which includes percent signs.

Comment: What is the reason you really need the output w/o escaping of the %? Can't you just replace the %% with %?

Comment: This is for a project which uses both raw SQL constructs and SQLAlchemy statements and we want to ensure that the SQL is executed by the engine (MySQL, Presto, etc.) in a consistent manner. Since neither approaches use parameters it seems prudent to mass the compiled SQL without the percentage escaping.